# Find out the active graphics driver using SetupAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, setupapi

I try to find out the version of the currently active graphics driver on Windows using C++ and SetupAPI. The solution roughly looks like

1. Call `SetupDiGetClassDevs` for `GUID_DEVCLASS_DISPLAY`.
2. Call `SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList` for the result set.
3. Call `SetupDiEnumDriverInfo` for the device set with `SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER`, which gives me all known drivers compatible with the GPU.

The result includes the fallback driver from Microsoft, which I can easily exclute, but it also includes all driver versions (from NVIDIA) that have been installed on the system.

The question is: How do I find out which of the drivers is actually running?

I know from the `SP_DEVINFO_DATA` returned in step 1 how the driver service is called and I also get some kind of registry key, but I do not see how I could relate this to the `SP_DRVINFO_DATA`. I also know that NVAPI provides driver management capabilities, but I would prefer a solution that works with GPUs of all kinds of vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the meantime at [Why does SetupDiEnumDriverInfo give two version numbers for my driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063402/why-does-setupdienumdriverinfo-give-two-version-numbers-for-my-driver): You need to update the install parameters of the device information set with the `DI_FLAGSEX_INSTALLEDDRIVER` flag before step 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, you can also query the `SPDRP_DRIVER` via `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` and then lookup that registry value under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\`. That key contains all the driver info. [Here](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/ThirdParty/ANGLE/src/gpu_info_util/SystemInfo_win.cpp) is some sample code from WebKit that actually retrieves GPU info this way.

Comment: Thanks. I have already looked into `SPDRP_DRIVER`, but I was not able to find any documentation on the root path in the registry.