# Get the currently "Active" driver for a device in C++

Tags: c++, windows, drivers, setupapi

I have used **SetupAPI** to enumerate all the drivers, build a list of its properties etc etc. But what i want is to enumerate only the "**Active**" drivers for any device.

Eg. For a Intel HD 5500, There are a couple of drivers installed in the System with different versions like

```
20.19.15.4531
20.19.15.4454
```

But the version shown in DeviceManager is 20.19.15.4531. I need to get only this version.

When I use SetupAPI,  I Get both the drivers. I've tried the solution listed at [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796791/find-out-the-active-graphics-driver-using-setupapi) but I can confirm that the solution does not work for me.

**SetupDiGetSelectedDriver()** also **does not work**. i.e. It works only when we are installing a driver to the store using SetupAPI functions.

Any Help will be really appreciated.

**Note :** There is no problem in finding and Enumerating the drivers. I use **SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList()** and **SetupDiEnumDrvInfo()**, and they work as expected.

Comment: Posting "does not work" instead of what you expected and what you got is likely to get downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally ended up building a list of current drivers using WMI in c++. Couldn't find a way out!